# How to convert Access statement to SQL to determine date range

Tags: sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010, dateadd

I have an Access statement that I am trying to convert to be used in SQL Server 2012.  Here is the statement:

```
>=DateAdd("m",-1,DateAdd("m",-12,Month(Now()) & "/" & [FiscalYear])) And <DateAdd("m",-1,DateAdd("m",-12,Month(Now()) & "/" & [FiscalYear]))+364
```

It is basically getting a rolling 12 month period.  How can I use this in SQL or is there a better way to write this altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would get the past 12 months worth of data in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DateField > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This works great except I am getting one date that I would not expect to get.  11/30/2017 and I believe it is in the second half of the statement that gets rid of that date.

Comment: I get the feeling your Access statement is doing more than just a rolling 12 month period then since I'm not sure why you wouldn't expect 11/30/2017 in a rolling 12 month period.  Can you explain?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but that is what the person who wrote it told me that it what it is doing.  The only thing I see there, is that is has +364 at the end and not +365.  That seems to be the issue as when I change it to +365, I get the 11/30/2017 date.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what it's saying now.  So if you were to run it today and run it, it would be something like the following:

>= 12/2016 AND < 12/2016 + 364

Comment: Basically, I think the reason you wouldn't expect 11/30/2017 is because it's strictly less than 12/2016 + 364.  It probably assumes 12/2016 is December 1st, and the 364 would put it on 11/30 so you shouldn't get that.  Try making the condition in the above query DateField >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) instead

Comment: I tried that on my own and I still get 11/30/2017 in the data.

Comment: The elegant solution you provided is correct.  I just confirmed that with the person who wrote the Access statement.  It should include the last date of that month.  He is unsure why he had +364.

Comment: Awesome!  Well hopefully that helped solve your problem if nothing else =)